# Odoo Real Time Field Validation

Tags: validation, odoo, odoo-14

I can validate a field using `@api.constrains`, but this method only works when I hit the save button. I want to validate a field in real-time when the user makes some changes. Is this possible in Odoo?

I know I can use @api.onchange, but it doesn't give me a warning in the field. I want something like red border in the field

[image]

Comment: You may want to do it in `@api.onchange` instead.

Comment: Yes I can but I want something like using regex

Comment: https://apps.odoo.com/apps/modules/12.0/num_validation/ This module is doing somethig similar get the idea and try to implement in 14
If you want to do this without messing in core modules you will need to make a js widget and us js to validate the value